# How to use Regex to tell if there are two non-alphanumeric charters together in string?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the requirement:

> If field contains characters other than alphanumeric characters,
>   space, single quote, or dash without beginning or ending with a space,
>   or two non-alphanumeric charters together, system displays error
>   message

This is what I done.

```
regx = /^(?![ '-])[a-zA-Z '-]{1,30}([^ '-])$/;
```

It does all the job but not "two non-alphanumeric charters together". If I want to examine if there are two non-alphanumeric charters together in the string (eg. First Name), how to write that?

And I don't know much about what I write means actually, comments are welcomed, I just look online and write that regx...

And I don't know why if I remove {1,30}, the compiler will report error.

By non-alphanumeric charters, I mean [ '-]

Comment: `/\W{2}/` <- 2 non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Please check if [`^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]$)(?!.*[ '-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dC4/1) is what you need. I assume the 2 non-alphanum characters are `[ '-]`, right? If  you mean all non-alphanum characters, then `\W` or `[^\w_]` (if you allow `_`) is correct. Not sure what error you get when removing `{1,30}`, I do not get any error, maybe you mean you do not get a match? If you allow min 2 characters, you can try [`^(?!.*[ '-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 '-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dC4/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to match strings with length from 1 to 30.

I suggest a regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dC4/1)) based on look-aheads to meet the requirements:

```
^(?![ ])(?!.*[ ]$)(?!.*[ '-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]{1,30}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dC4/1)

Here, the 2 non-alphanumeric characters that cannot appear consecutively are `[ '-]`. The `(?![ ])`  look-ahead makes sure the string does not start with a space (replace `[ ]` with `\s` if any whitespace is meant, by the way). The `(?!.*[ ]$)` lookahead makes sure the string (without newline symbols - else, replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*`) does not end with a space. The `(?!.*[ '-]{2})` lookahead makes sure there are no consecutive non-word symbols , `'`, or `-` in the string (again, use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` if you have newline symbols in the string).

You can also use an expression with just 2 look-aheads to minimize overhead:

```
^(?!.*[ '-]{2})(?![ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]{0,29}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dC4/3)

If you could allow minimum 2 characters, you could use a more optimal [`^(?!.*[ '-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 '-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/zN7dC4/2), but I guess it is not the case.

Note in your regex, you have `&` instead of `$` (end of string/line) and you did not allow digits (alphanumeric symbols usually include letters and digits).

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to examine if there are two non-alphanumeric charters
>   together in the string (eg. First Name), how to write that?

```
/[^a-zA-Z\d]{2}/g
```

I'll leave it to you to determine how to incorporate that into your regex. Check out [this site](http://www.regexr.com/) for help building Regular expressions. It's saved me a bunch of times :)

Comment: But the main issue he is having is precisely **how** to incorporate that into his regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should work: `/\W{2}|[^\w' -]|^ (.*) $/`

```js
var reg = /\W{2}|[^\w' -]|^ (.*) $/;
var strings = ['My own text', 'This. Is a bad string', 'This  is also a bad string', ' This is also a bad string '];
strings.forEach(function(string){
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += 'String: "' + string + '" is valid? ' + (string.match(reg) === null) + '\n';
  });
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*\W\W)(?![ '-])[a-zA-Z '-]{1,30}([^ '-])$

  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Just add a `lookahead` to make sure `non-alphanumeric charters` `\W` doesnt come `2` times.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/40